# Latest VMProtect vs Latest Themida

Tags: c++, protection

I am working on an app to archive some important files in a compressed-encrypted format,

What is the best for me to use (Virtualization) VMProtector or Themida ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Both work with virtualization techniques, I recommend vm protect from experience and consider it slightly better in machine protection, buy the latest version, if you know how to try adding some of your own techniques, but I believe that only vm protect is enough to the protection of the executable, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I already have the both protections and latest versions and I was using Themida for a while BUT recently someone test the app for me and he is able to extract all my virtualized codes, in the other hand I know a lot of cracked softwares and they use VMProtect software so I am confused a little, Could you explain difference and real experience to me Please ?

Comment: first sorry for my bad english, as i understand the case, this was a memory dump to get the virtualization code of the themida or vm protect, basically it reached the point of decompression and made a dump, yes, it is possible to do this, more the virtualization techniques the instructions are different, making a static analysis of the executable difficult, on the other hand, a dynamic analysis is possible, if you can make a hook, in my experiences I was successful, but it really is complex / laborious and many companies don't spend time doing that.

Comment: So Themida is better against the Memory code dump or the VMProtect ?, Thanks for your info

Comment: the two recent versions offer excellent protection against, dump is inevitable, what matters is how the virtualization codes are created, I have a golden tip, under the demo versions, we protect the executable and we try to analyze it, it is kind of hard to say which is rather, it varies a lot of opinion, I would use VM Protect.

Comment: Could you test for me a protected app ?. (for a price)

Comment: I am grateful, but due to contracts I cannot, but I am sure that you will find an excellent professional to do this, good luck.